# Can I marinate chicken that has already been cooked?

Tags: chicken, meat, grilling, marinade

I have some chicken that was grilled. I want to put it back on the grill and cook it some more. I marinated it in a bag. Is it OK to marinate cooked chicken?

Comment: Can you clarify and add more information?  Cook...put back in bag...cook again?  Is the marinade refrigerated during first cook?  Is the chicken chilled after first cook and before second marinade? How long between first cook and second cook?  Is it refrigerated during this time?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you will get the same effect by marinating chicken after it's cooked. It will not absorb much of the marinade.